# Add records from Excel vba to Ms Access adding blanks instead

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, record

I've been trying to find a way to add records from excel to my ms access table and after searching and watching videos I managed to have the code below.
However it keeps adding blanks.
The excel data has the same headers with the same names on the access table minus the first column in access that contains its own numbered column

Does anyone know why?
code below

```
Sub AddRecords()
        
    Dim accessFile  As String
    Dim accessTable As String
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastColumn  As Integer
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
accessFile = "C:\Users\...\Novo.accdb"
accessTable = "TBL_Database_AVD"
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dados")

With sht
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile

sql = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.CursorType = 1  
rs.LockType = 3    
  
rs.Open sql, con

For i = 3 To lastRow

    rs.AddNew
    For j = 1 To lastColumn

        rs(sht.Cells(i, j).Value) = sht.Cells(i, j).Value

    Next j

    rs.Update

Next i

rs.Close
con.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: At a first glance I'd say this line `rs(sht.Cells(i, j).Value) = sht.Cells(i, j).Value`  cannot work and it should throw an error. You have to use the syntax `rs.fields (index).value =`  or `rs.fields ("fieldname").value =`

Comment: @Storax thank you! :) added |||||   a = Cells(2, j).Value  |||||  and then used your second suggestion |||||   rs.fields (a).value =sht.Cells(i, j).Value ||||| and it worked. Thank you.